# SimpleDateFormat shows wrong value for day of the extracted date

Tags: java

I am trying to separately extract date and time from a DateTime string but the code shows wrong date.

**Code**

```
    String dateTime= "2015-12-10T14:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat frm1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = frm1.parse(dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat frm2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    String date1 = frm2.format(date);
    System.err.println(date1);
    SimpleDateFormat frm3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String time = frm3.format(date);
    System.err.println(time);
```

**Output**

```
28/12/2015
14:00
```

Comment: It shows exactly what the formats you specified says that it should.

Comment: to negative voter, I am not a genius so it would be so difficult for me to find out your reason of negative voting. Please explain then.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it shows 28/12/2015 but the input is 2015-12-10

Comment: What is your format?

Comment: YYYY-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss is input and dd/MM/YYYY is output

Comment: What does `YYYY` represent? What does `MM` represent? What does `mm` represent? Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry do not get you

Comment: Why did you use `YYYY`? Why did you use `MM`? Why did you use `mm`?

Comment: MM is month yyyy is year dd is day

Comment: `yyyy` is year or `YYYY` is year?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis got it, Daniel's code works thanks for your help.

Comment: You had to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code also refer to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String dateTime= "2015-12-10T14:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat frm1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = frm1.parse(dateTime);
        SimpleDateFormat frm2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date1 = frm2.format(date);
        System.err.println(date1);
        SimpleDateFormat frm3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String time = frm3.format(date);
        System.err.println(time);




Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day in week Text    Tuesday; Tue
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

Comment: whats the negative vote for? are you playing with the votes? :D you should explain it mate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because it is returning the expected result, I also included the link to correct formatting. What else should I do ?

Comment: Explain what you changed and why you changed it. If the link has useful information, extract those things which are important and add them to your answer.

Comment: Probably he is expecting an explanation for why the OP's code didnt work. A cap `Y` meant it was a [Week Year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year) and not normal year.

Comment: *"Try this*" is a downvote magnet unless it's followed up with some kind of explanation of "why" they should or how it fixes there problem.  Code dumps teach nothing and only serve to further limit the people in the feature. Why I don't dispute your results, we want to know if you actually know "why" the answer works yourself, or did you just copy it from somewhere else. Just so you know for next time ;

Comment: @MadProgrammer alright thanks for your explanation, I included the link to the table as well to make sure Jack would know the reason. I also did not change much of the code the modified part is obvious.